# What is 'kernel times' in Windows Task Manager

Tags: python, windows, multiprocessing, kernel

This is my task manager when running some Python `multiprocessing` tasks.

[image]

The shaded parts are "kernel times". Are those the utilization associated with my Python program, or the basic Windows OS tasks?

In other words, am I really utilizing most of the computing capacity or just a fraction?

I Googled around and every explanation I've seen is along the line of "kernel times are the time spent on kernel tasks", which is not helpful.

Comment: Where does your graphic use the term "kernel times"? Anyway, what people call kernel time is just time spent in operating system (i.e. Windows) code,. This would include work it is doing on behalf of your application, for instance when you are doing disk I/O. But the CPU percentage shown in your graphic includes all CPU being used, which is not just "kernel time." If you are running at 100%, then all the capacity of your CPU is being used. By what or whom is not clear.

Comment: If you right-click on a chart, it'll say "Show Kernel Times", and the shaded area will appear. My guess is the Python programme is "occupying" those CPU threads, but not really "using" them intensely, if the shaded area is assigned to Python. Note I don't have much else running on the side.

Comment: I learn something new every day! When I do this on my desktop, there seem to be two curves superimposed on one another: Total CPU percentage as a function of time and Kernel CPU percentage as a function of time. The latter is shaded and naturally lies below the former. I can't quite discern two curves on your graphic. Is this because the kernel is taking up all 100%? I would think that to be an unusual situation. What is your multiprocessing worker function doing?

Comment: It's not unusualy if you use up all CPU cores with Python's `multiprocessing` module. Each worker is running some `scipy` optimizations but that's irrelevant to the question really.

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/understanding-user-and-kernel-mode/

Comment: @Aaron Thank you. So from the snapshot in my question, Python is actually using most of the computing power of all those threads, while OS kernel code is taking up a small fraction.

Comment: @JingweiYu a portion of the kernel mode time is likely also related to your code as well, as certain calls (particularly OS operations) require kernel functions to be called. For example, allocating new memory pages requires a kernel call.

Comment: I can not add to this topic, but I want to highlight how awsome it is to have an answer to a random question in my mind. :D Thank guys :)